# Which HTTP Headers are absolutely required for the GAE doPost/doGet methods?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, http, http-headers

I'm developing a mobile application that transmits data to the google app engine once per minute, always and forever. The mobile user is charged per megabyte for data usage. The body of each request I need to send is only a hundred bytes or so; I'm trying to optimize the requests to save on data usage.

My question: what HTTP headers are absolutely required for the App Engine to be able to correctly handle a request via the `doPost` or `doGet` methods? Are they different? Which method is optimal for data usage? I want to strip out any header that is non-essential.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

-tjw

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to HTTP/1.1, only Host is required.

Other headers, like Content-type, *should* be specified, but if your service can infer them, they may be omitted.

You should test the efficiency of [compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression) on your messages. For such small messages, it might not help, but if it does, you should use it.

Comment: I don't think the type of data I send is very compressible; but thanks for the info. The GAE has a lot of interesting idiosyncracies, so I'd like to hear from someone who has specific experience with the GAE before accepting your answer. +1, thanks.

Comment: @Travis App Engine is an HTTP service. As such, it follows HTTP/1.1. This answer is correct.

Comment: Well, GAE *does* have some oddities; for example its "JPA" provider can only be considered a JPA provider with air-quotes. Google knows HTTP, so I'm more confident it will be satisfied with the minimum required headers, but actual testing would be nice.

Comment: @Nick There are other standards the GAE purports to follow but doesn't, so I wanted to double check. Thanks.

Comment: JDO, JPA, javax.script, The Java Servlet standard, java.net, arbitrary JVM-level limits, off the top of my head. Nick I really don't want to get into an argument with you; the app engine is great, we use it to host several applications, but it has standards issues that have cost us a lot of development time.